# sed to modify only first column in a file but not the first occurrence if it matches

Tags: regex, sed

I want to update only the first column in a file but the not the first occurrence. below is the code I am currently using to update the first occurrence.

To modify first occurrence of a date

```
sed 's/\(....\)-\(..\)-\(..\)/\2\/\3\/\1/'
```

I am facing some problems like some times the date is in the right format, which is in the first column so the above code is modifying the date in third or fourth column as it is the first occurrence. which I don't want

below is what I am doing:

```
2018-09-14^Aaaa^Aq^ATEST^Abc^2018-09-14^A1^2018-09-14

sed 's/\(....\)-\(..\)-\(..\)/\2\/\3\/\1/' 

2018/14/09^Aaaa^Aq^ATEST^Abc^2018-09-14^A1^2018-09-14
```

Some rows in my file are in right format and some don't . So I only want to modify the first column in a file if its not matching "yyyy/mm/dd" format and ignore if it is already in "yyyy/mm/dd" format.

Output I want

```
$cat test.csv
2018/14/09^Aaa^Aa^ATEST^Abc^2018-09-14^A1^2018-09-14
2018-09-14^Aaa^Aa^ATEST^Abc^2018-09-14^A1^2018-09-14
To
$ cat output_test.csv
2018/14/09^Aaa^Aa^ATEST^Abc^2018-09-14^A1^2018-09-14
2018/14/09^Aaa^Aa^ATEST^Abc^2018-09-14^A1^2018-09-14
```

Comment: `2018/14/09` is in the right yyyy/mm/dd format?

Comment: Not bothering about yyyy/mm/dd or yyyy/dd/mm . Just how to change only in first column on if it matches.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
$cat test.csv |sed -E 's/^(\w+)-(\w\w)-(\w\w)/\1\/\3\/\2/'
```

then for real editing:

```
$ sed -i -E 's/^(\w+)-(\w\w)-(\w\w)/\1\/\3\/\2/' test.csv >output_test.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU or OSX/BSD sed for `-E` to enable EREs:

```
$ sed -E 's:^([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^^]+):\1/\3/\2:' test.csv
2018/14/09^Aaa^Aa^ATEST^Abc^2018/14/09^A1^2018-09-14
2018/14/09^Aaa^Aa^ATEST^Abc^2018-09-14^A1^2018-09-14
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the begin with(^) pattern to match:

```
sed 's/^\(....\)-\(..\)-\(..\)/\1\/\3\/\2/' file
```